# Python get rid of bytes b' '

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import save

string = ""

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != b"":
        byte = f.read(1)
        print ((byte))
```

I'm getting bytes like:

`b'\x00'`

How do I get rid of this `b''`?

Let's say I wanna save the bytes to a list, and then save this list as the same image again. How do I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: The `b` means it's a byte... you don't want to get rid of it...

Comment: `byte.decode('ascii')` if you know that the byte represents an ASCII character

Comment: @Pithikos bytes.decode('ascii'), to correct it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use bytes.decode function if you really need to "get rid of b": http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

But it seems from your code that you do not really need to do this, you really need to work with bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The b"..." is just a python notation of byte strings, it's not really there, it only gets printed. Does it cause some real problems to you?

Comment: When I save it to a txt it saves with the b''

Comment: I see, you are saving it as string. If that is the problem then str(byte)[1:] should remove the 'b'

Comment: it's python slice syntax. "string"[1:] takes string character from index 1 till the end: it produces "tring". See python docs fore more references on slicing :)

Answer (score 3):

The `b''`, is only the string representation of the data that is written when you `print` it.

Using `decode` will not help you here because you only want the bytes, not the characters they represent. Slicing the string representation will help even less because then you are still left with a string of several useless characters ('\', 'x', and so on), not the original bytes.

There is no need to modify the string representation of the data, because the data is still there. Just use it instead of the string (i.e. don't use `print`). If you want to copy the data, you can simply do:

```
data = file1.read(...)
...
file2.write(data)
```

If you want to output the binary data directly from your program, use the `sys.stdout.buffer`:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

To operate on binary data you can use the [array-module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html#module-array).
Below you will find an iterator that operates on 4096 chunks of data instead of reading everything into memory at ounce.

```
import array

def bytesfromfile(f):
    while True:
        raw = array.array('B')
        raw.fromstring(f.read(4096))
        if not raw:
            break
        yield raw

with open("image.jpg", 'rb') as fd
    for byte in bytesfromfile(fd):
        for b in byte:
            # do something with b
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to get rid of the `b''`:

```
import sys
print(b)
```

If you want to save the bytes later it's more efficient to read the entire file in one go rather than building a list, like this:

```
with open('sample.jpg', mode='rb') as fh:
    content = fh.read()
    with open('out.jpg', mode='wb') as out:
        out.write(content)
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is one solution

`print(str(byte[2:-1]))`

Comment: That's flawed.   You mean `str(byte)[2:-1]` (note the different bracket placement). However, even when corrected it's not a very forward-/backward-compatible, or transparent/maintainable, way to do it.