# python convert b'123' to '123'

Tags: python

I receive a row of bytes over a socket connection as data. When I `print(data)` it tells me

```
b'123'
```

How can I convert it back to a string and only print `123`? If I do `type(data)` it puts out

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

When I do data.decode("utf-8") it puts me out 'bytes' object has no attribute 'decode'. Do I mix something up with the type?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you must be mixing up two different `data` objects.  The one you examined with `print(data)` and `type(data)` is a `bytes` object and it will have a `.decode()` method.   If the error is `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` then you are dealing with a different `data`, one that is (evidently) a `str` object rather than a `bytes` object.

Comment: So why does it show me <class 'bytes'> after I print(type(data)). Is it a mistake by python3? Should it be <class 'str'>?

Comment: I'm saying try it again. Recreate `data` from scratch, examine its type, and then look for its `decode` method.  Previously, you must have changed `data` without realizing it, in between those two actions. Over and out.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong above. After print(data.encode('utf-8')) it says AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: datax = str(b"xxx")   #string
print (datax)

also prints out b'xxx' This is wrong? Why is that?

Comment: I dont get it in python3datax = str(b"xxx") 
print (datax)
puts out b'xxx' whyy?????

Comment: Ah, that's a different confusion but easier to straighten out.  `bytes` objects have a decode method but not encode;  `str` objects, vice versa.   That's because it's an asymmetric system: you "decode" a `bytes` object into a `str`, and conversely "encode" a `str` object into a `bytes`.    `str(x)` is no longer the approved way to convert a `bytes` object `x` to `str` - it just gives you some sort of printable representation, in this case (IMO stupidly) the same as `repr(b)`. The powers that be want to force you to use `.decode` explicitly.

Comment: data.decode("uft-8") does not work as well. Why is it so difficult to convert this stuff. Do I need a regex to cut b"*" out or what... come on python3

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: ok SOLUTION http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013089/python-get-rid-of-bytes-b

Comment: print (str(datax[2:-1]))

Comment: datawithoutb = str(data)[2:-1]
      print(datawithoutb)